# Infinite scroll with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add infinite scrolling functionality to my html web page using vanilla javascript, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I have written only a few lines of html code. Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Infinite Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="image4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="image5.jpg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

And I have written no css, as i only want to focus on javascript for now.
The scrolling should kind of work like the bootstrap carousel.
Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Any research?

Comment: Yes. At first I tried it on my own. But since I am new to javascript, I could not even write a few lines of code. So, I tried searching online, but the results from trusted sites used frameworks like jquery, which was just a bit overwhelming for me.

Comment: I suggest you to learn the basics before attempting an infinite scrolling with ajax requests.  Because infinite scrolings are done with ajax requests to a server. You need to request items 1 to 10, then 11 to 20, then 21 to 30. You need a REST API that responds to this. You need to parse the JSON data and iterate it to update your DOM. Really, I believe that this is way beyond your level for now. One step at a time son :)

Answer (score 1):

Carousel and infinite scroll are not the same thing. But before creating complex stuff, you should accept to learn to create simple things.

A good idea could be to focus on some basic steps

1. Only have two image
2. Hide the second one with css
3. Add a 'next' button, that does nothing
4. Learn how to console.log when button is clicked
5. Change your button code to hide the first image and display the second one
6. Find a way to loop, displaying the first one if next pressed when second one is displayed
7. Add a third image to test your loop
8. Add a 'previous' button
9. Be sure your code works with a variable number of images

So, you just created a carousel

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks a lot for your help!